# No power to part of my townhouse

Tags: receptacle

I live in a Townhouse. I have no power except on one level upstairs.

Power Box is all good. I am a nurse not an electrician.

Thoughts please.

Comment: We are going to need more info. What does "*Power Box is all good*" mean? Do you know how to reset a breaker in the breaker box?   Please describe any events that led to this situation.

Comment: Sounds like more of problem than what you can fix.  Getting a electrician in to see what is happening is your best bet.  It might be a problem with the wires coming from power company(cheap fix) or something is wrong on your side of the meter, both should be fixed now.

Comment: Check with your neighbors to see if they have the same problem as you.

Comment: Call the power company. You could have a dead leg to your power. Costs nothing to at least have them check

Comment: If the townhouse is a rental, call the landlord.

Comment: During daytime, or under adequate light, in the electric panel (box), switch all circuit breakers off,  then switch them one-by-one back on, and notice the light in each area. If some areas remain in dark, you shall call an electrician immediately. Do not wait, it means there is something wrong in the circuits, that may have safety concerns.

Comment: Is there any pattern to which circuits do and don't have power, relative to the way they're laid out in the power box?

Comment: Can you add a clear photo of the switches in your distribution box ?